# Mylyn alternative for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, mylyn

We have been using Unfuddle in our company for 1 year. All my colleagues can easily access Unfuddle tickets using Eclipse addon called Mylyn.

Does something like this exist for IntelliJ IDEA?

If not, can you suggest some alternative way to deal with Unfuddle tickets from IDEA?

Comment: Please vote for the plugin on the JetBrains website: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/wishlist/show?pr=&wid=65

Comment: @Edward: Link is 404.

Comment: I could not find a newer version of the wishlist - seems to be abolished.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They guys at IntelliJ forum confirmed that such alternative does not exist. We hope this will change one day.

Answer (score 18):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3 you can click on **Tools->Tasks & Contexts->Configure servers**.

It has a behavior close to Mylyn has.

Check also the answer bellow about the plugin "Focus on Active Task"

Regards

Comment: This needs to get upvoted more as this is the latest answer to the question

Answer (score 9):

**Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin mentioned in this post.**

I suggest trying out the [Focus on Active Task](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9824-focus-on-active-task) plugin from the JetBrains repository, that I made a while ago.

This attempts to emulate Eclipse Mylyn's main functionality, by adding a `Focus on Active Task` toggle action on the View menu that filters the project tree with the currently active task/opened files.

`Alt+click` will also behave close to Mylyn's feature by temporarily unfiltering (showing all children of) specific tree nodes.

Comment: Excellent I will try it out

Comment: Nice! Is the source code available? It seems like it only filters the project view and not functions like mylyn can do (mylyn can collapse non-task functions and filter the structure view too)

Comment: @olejorgenb Thanks! Code isn't published atm, but I do plan to open source it at some point. I'll make sure to mention you again when it's done (hopefully in the coming weeks). And yes, it's still minimal compared to what Mylyn can do.

Comment: How could I reset the context? Thanks!

Comment: @卢声远ShengyuanLu Can you explain what you mean by "reset the context"? Right now, the focused items (files) on the project view are synchronized with the open editor files. Whichever ones are open will be shown on the project view (unless you Alt+click a folder, which will temporarily reveal all files within it). You can use Ctrl+Shift+Q (default shortcut) to disable the filtering temporarily and then enable it back later.

Comment: @Jeto sometimes I have *multiple tasks* to do, could I have multiple 'Active Task' to switch?

Comment: @卢声远ShengyuanLu Sure, that's the whole point! You can make use of IntelliJ's [Tasks and contexts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html) feature (you don't need to connect any issue tracker btw, just creating local tasks is enough), and then whenever you switch to another task, the IDE will remember the open editor files and the plugin will refresh the project tree accordingly. Let me know if that works for you.